Single-argument variable template specilization causes instantiation?
Here's the minimal example of the question:
I have 3 source files:
// A.h
template<class T> int var = 2;

// A1.cpp
template<> int var<int> = 3;
template int var<int>;

// A2.cpp
template<> int var<double> = 4;
template int var<double>;

But the linker reported 2 errors saying that var<double> and var<int> symbols are already defined. After commenting out either template<> int var<double> = 4; template<> int var<int> = 3; or the lines below them, the linking process terminated normally. I opened the generated lib file with IDA, and found the 2 variables are right inside.
I used to think that template<> int var<double> is some kind of template specilization without instantiation while template int var<double> is instantiation of the template. But now it seems they are the same, i.e. the specialization seems to cause instantiation. Am I wrong?

Variable templates are implicitly instantiated when referenced. Can you clarify why do you think you need the instatiation lines (like template int var<int>;) to begin with ?

You need the declaration of the specialization in header (template<> int var<int>;).

template int var<int>; is explicit instantiation, template<> int var<int>; is declaration of the specialization and finally template<> int var<int> = 42; is the definition of the specialization.

Any usages of the specialization should see the declaration (or the definition).

@wohlstad Because I used to think that a specialization of template is still a template just with relatively fewer arguments, thus it still need to be instantiated to create a symbol in the binary.

@Jarod42 Yes, I know the difference, and what I didn't understand is why a specialization of template will be compiled into the binary and create a symbol, this will cause redefinition.

"a specialization of template is still a template" this is true of partial speializations, but not full specializations. Full specialization are no longer templates but real classes, functions or variables, just with a fancy name. E.g. you can't take an address of var<T>, but you can of var<int> - it's an object that actually occupies memory and has an address.

"why a specialization of template will be compiled into the binary and create a symbol" It's not the specialiation template<> int var<int> that does that, but the explicit instantiation template int var<int>. That's kinda the whole point of explicit instantiation.

@NekomiyaKasane You should provide a [mcve] where you show if you're using the header A.h anywhere.

Using a template before it's specialized?


[temp.expl.spec]/7 If a template ... is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

In your case, if some translation unit includes A.h and then refers to var<int> or var<double>, your program is ill-formed (no diagnostic required) under this clause.
It's a good thing that you actually get an error.
